# Как макросом убрать тире между цифр в Google Sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, макросы

Имеется столбце с телефонными номерами. Хотелось бы, что бы после ввода телефонного номера с тире, эти тире автоматически удалялись. Возможно ли такое сделать макросом? Работаю в Google Sheets.

Comment: Тема противоречит описанию: в теме про тире, в описании про пробелы

Answer (score 1):

На основе примера № 8 из [Примеры, Google Apps Script](https://codd-wd.ru/shpargalka-dopolneniya-dlya-google-tablic-spreadsheets-i-ispolzovanie-google-apps-script/). Далее скрипт надо встроить - см. скриншоты ниже.

Примечание. Для отладки можно использовать [эти подходы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e === undefined) return false; // если аргумент не определен, выходим
  
  const shName = 'Телефоны'; // имя контролируемого листа 
  const colNumber = 2; // номер колонки, где контролировать изменения
  const dateOffset = 12; // смещение, куда ставить дату

  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getSheet().getName() != shName | range.getColumn() != colNumber) return false;
 
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) { // перебираем все строки, где произошли изменения, в нужном столбце
    var cell = range.getCell(i,1);
    cell.setValue(cell.getValue().toString().replace(/[-\s]/g,"")); // удаляет все пробелы и тире 
    cell.offset(0,dateOffset).setValue(new Date()); // ставим дату
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня 2 макроса получается, и второй, этот, вызывает ошибки.. Может я что-то делаю не так...

Comment: Если вы опишете все детально в вопросе, будет возможность разобраться. Сейчас информация о том, что у вас происходит, есть только у вас.

Comment: Не знаю, как соединить 2 макроса ... я их никогда не делал. Сейчас вот так. Просто вставил вторйо макрос под первым - https://pastebin.com/3UicTh9x

Comment: Начните с малого. Оставьте один, отладьте, потом принимайтесь за второй и их объединение. А еще лучше почитайте документацию.

Comment: Верхний работает :) Проблема со вторым...

Comment: У меня работает, проблем никаких :) и вы не пишете, что за ошибки. Поэтому я не смогу ничего посоветовать, кроме того, что уже посоветовал.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Comment: Исходя из ошибки, вы не привязали функцию к триггеру (см. выше), а запускаете ее вручную. Поэтому аргумент `e` не определен. Смотрите на скриншотах выше, как привязать функцию к триггеру. Тогда она будет срабатывать, когда вы правите ячейку.

Comment: А если мне надо столбец H, что бы макрос отслеживал, то пишем вместо 1 - 8?

И будет ли макрос отслеживать каждую строчку?

Comment: А если мне надо столбец H, что бы макрос отслеживал, то пишем вместо 1 - 8? И будет ли макрос отслеживать каждую строчку?
Так же появилась ошибка...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined
    at onEdit(OnEdit:5:21)

Comment: Обновил код. Совместил с функцией вашего скрипта

Comment: Спасибо! Перепроверил. Дата ставится, пробелы и тире в 8ом столбце не убираются

Журналы Cloud Console
20 нояб. 2022 г., 22:35:39 Ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined
    at onEdit(OnEdit:10:13)

Мне необходимо, что бы после ввода текста в 1ом столбце, ставилась дата в 12ый. Но телефонные номера с пробелами и тире находятся в 8ом....